# Why does my power automate flow run keep running and does not stop?

Tags: excel, power-automate

**Problem:**
I am getting a never-ending loop/ the flow never ends, and it keeps re-adding some of the data and does not stop.

The loops work but they never stop and it just keeps re-adding the data that was already added and does not stop. So instead of my excel file being small, the flow does not stop until I manually trigger the "Stop test".

**Information of the problem:**
Hello,

I am getting a never-ending loop/ the flow never ends, and it keeps re-adding some of the data and does not stop. Basically, I have a manual trigger -> reads a pdf -> unstructured document model ai that reads the pdf text -> then updates a excel sheet.

**My data flow:**

[image]

**What have I done? :**
But every time I fill out the columns with the A.I variables in image 2, it keeps creating these "for each loops" automatically forcing me to use it. For example, when I fill the date variable it creates 3 for each loops. The loops work but they never stop and it just keeps re-adding the data that was already added and does not stop. So instead of my excel file being small, the flow does not stop until I manually trigger the "Stop test"

**My Goal:**
My goal is to put the data into the excel file once. Currently, the flow does not stop and it keeps readding the same data.

**Excel data flow:**

[image]

```
{
  "type": "Foreach",
  "foreach": "@outputs('Extract_information_from_forms')?['body']?['responsev2']?['predictionOutput']?['tables']?['Automate597bbeef311f5b9e0df340f0b0a68c1d']?['entries']",
  "actions": {
    "For_each_2": {
      "type": "Foreach",
      "foreach": "@outputs('Extract_information_from_forms')?['body']?['responsev2']?['predictionOutput']?['tables']?['Crew_0022c7ee1247c02ccb3a711d582c9d73db6']?['columns']",
      "actions": {
        "Add_a_row_into_a_table": {
          "type": "OpenApiConnection",
          "inputs": {
            "parameters": {
              "source": "me",
              "drive": "b!FPgrkPStAEy4OoAy8HSHSh9vj2lzn6NNkSAJ-Qng1xsZEK-K7iylQL0dL_Hgtahh",
              "file": "01U47DLXCASRZ644OEOFAKMPS2YQMJTEYR",
              "table": "{74525493-0328-48EB-87BD-BDE5B61B208F}",
              "item/Date": "@items('For_each')?['Date']?['text']",
              "item/Job(s)": "@items('For_each')?['Hours_004569f0b6a7e8769364f074183f28efc5']?['text']",
              "item/Hours - Job": "@items('For_each')?['Hours_004569f0b6a7e8769364f074183f28efc5']?['text']",
              "item/Hours - Break": "@items('For_each')?['Hours_002cc024136d3c5e0c504613bab2af61e1']?['text']",
              "item/Hours - NPT": "@items('For_each')?['Hours_004c7f46d00c82aee4ec2077b9d28dd7df']?['text']",
              "item/Hours - Paid": "@items('For_each')?['Hours_0065a7f71a8030420e08c2167e75128771']?['text']",
              "item/Time Pay": "@items('For_each')?['Time_002fde14afb3a20b37487e67d9d67a448e0']?['text']",
              "item/Production Pay": "@items('For_each')?['Producti132efa0c6b566deed804341b17203544']?['text']",
              "item/Additional Pay - Hours": "@items('For_each')?['Addition27035ec9bb9dd92bd16749ecc4676356']?['text']",
              "item/Additional Pay - Pay": "@items('For_each')?['Addition02f1f00c7e089920922b99d42a2a6e91']?['text']",
              "item/Total": "@items('For_each')?['Total']?['text']",
              "item/Crew Name": "@items('For_each_2')?['name']"
            },
            "host": {
              "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_excelonlinebusiness",
              "connection": "shared_excelonlinebusiness",
              "operationId": "AddRowV2"
            }
          },
          "metadata": {
            "01U47DLXHVSEWL4M7DTNBYYBS4OWC5SLCH": "/Desktop/11.8 - PDF to Excel Test copy.xlsx",
            "tableId": "{74525493-0328-48EB-87BD-BDE5B61B208F}",
            "01U47DLXGFKLOTLTAIH5H3POPMDQ2FTTGZ": "/Desktop/11.8 - PDF to Excel Test.xlsx",
            "operationMetadataId": "7e33223c-b137-4c43-89b7-72305f77874e",
            "01U47DLXCASRZ644OEOFAKMPS2YQMJTEYR": "/Desktop/TEST 12.xlsx"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {
    "Extract_information_from_forms": [
      "Succeeded"
    ]
  }
}
```

**What have I tried to do to fix this?**

1. I have tried to remove the loops; the flow provides me with error.
2. Tried to add a do until. It does not even extract any data into the excel file. I think I did it wrong though.
3. Tried to add a "terminate" action, but it would not work since the flow does not even fail or succeed.

Comment: You need to show us the data that comes out of the form extraction step before the loops start. PASTE IT AS TEXT!!! Do not paste it as an image.

Comment: @Skin, here is the link where I posted more information related to the question. Here I included the text and some other information related to the flow: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Why-does-my-power-automate-flow-run-keep-running-and-does-not/m-p/2544739#M284455

Comment: Sorry but it's really hard to follow, your screenshots on the link have two loops where here it has three and with the data you provided doesn't match up with your JSON definition.  Can you just give me the response data from the `Extract_information_from_forms` output?  I'll then build it for you but can't do it without that.  You need to paste it in here, just edit your question.